# "Revert to last revision" action

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I made an update to a site for global search and replace of text across nodes and was too far-reaching. For a specific content type I need to revert my Node update of ~500 nodes.

I found this solution in the VBO issue queue:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1166630

But in evaluating this code a new revision is made by it is *not* set as the `current revision` of the node. If I visit the node revisions page and invoke `node_revision_revert_confirm_submit` a new `current_revision` is set for the node.

[image]
Code I'm trying:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_action_info().
 */
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function revert_last_revision_action_info() {
  $action = array(
    'REVERT_LAST_REVISION' => array(
      'label'        => t('Revert to Last Revision'),
      'type'         => 'node',
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers'     => array('any'),
    ),
  );
  return $action;
}

/**
 * Action function for REVERT_LAST_REVISION.
 */
function REVERT_LAST_REVISION(&$entity, $context = array()) {
  $node = $entity;
  $revision_list = node_revision_list($node);
  unset($revision_list[$node->vid]);
  if (count($revision_list) > 0) {
    $last_revision = max(array_keys($revision_list));
    $node_last_revision = node_load($node->nid, $last_revision);
    $node_last_revision->revision = TRUE;
    $node_last_revision->log = "Reverted via bulk operation action."; // Log message
    dpm($node_last_revision, __FUNCTION__);
    node_save($node_last_revision);
  }
}
```

Using devel the `$node` arrays look the same so I'm confused as to why my revert revision code snippet is not making the new revision the `current_revision`. The only thing `node_revision_revert_confirm_submit` is doing is setting `$node->revision = TRUE` and calling `node_save()`.

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT: 11/16/2015**

As others have mentioned perhaps this has to do with how VBO is initiating the action.

I've also tried the below code but the Node isn't saved.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function revert_last_revision_action_info() {
  $action = array(
    'REVERT_LAST_REVISION' => array(
      'label'        => t('Revert to Last Revision'),
      'type'         => 'node',
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers'     => array('any'),
      'behavior'     => array('changes_property'),
      'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
      'pass rows'        => TRUE,
    ),
  );
  return $action;
}

/**
 * Action function for REVERT_LAST_REVISION.
 */
function REVERT_LAST_REVISION(&$entity, $context = array()) {
  $revision_list = node_revision_list($entity);
  unset($revision_list[$entity->vid]);
  if (count($revision_list) > 0) {
    $last_revision = max(array_keys($revision_list));
    $entity = node_load($entity->nid, $last_revision, TRUE);
    $entity->revision = TRUE;
    $entity->log = "Reverted via bulk operation action.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much debugging this appears to work. This code appears to revert to the most recent revision properly and does not cause a 2nd node save to occur:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function revert_last_revision_action_info() {
  $action = array(
    'REVERT_LAST_REVISION' => array(
      'label'        => t('Revert to Last Revision'),
      'type'         => 'node',
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers'     => array('any'),
      'behavior'     => array('view_property'),
    ),
  );
  return $action;
}

/**
 * Action function for REVERT_LAST_REVISION.
 */
function REVERT_LAST_REVISION(&$entity, $context = array()) {
  $revision_list = node_revision_list($entity);
  unset($revision_list[$entity->vid]);
  if (count($revision_list) > 0) {
    $last_revision = max(array_keys($revision_list));
    $entity = entity_revision_load('node', $last_revision);
    $entity->revision = TRUE;
    $entity->log = "Reverted via bulk operation action.";
    entity_save('node', $entity);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what is causing the final node save in [ViewsBulkOperationsAction::execute](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views_bulk_operations%21plugins%21operation_types%21action.class.php/function/ViewsBulkOperationsAction%3A%3Aexecute/7) to not fire? I can't tell if it's because of the action info behaviors not set as: `save`, `pre-save`, or `changes_property` values. Or perhaps it's the usage of `entity_save` here  instead of a `node_save` ...

I've debugged this with a few nodes using Batch and single nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the node is saved twice: Once in the custom action and once from the the Views Bulk Operations action. Because the `$entity` object hasn't been changed, `entity_save()` saves the previous version of the node, thus setting the node back to previous revision instead of the newly created one.

Comment: Hmmm ... I swear I've tried the code removing the "local" node and local save .... But then my node wasn't saved .... Grrrrr